# How to distinguish folders from files in a batch script? (Or how to copy & rename-timestamp them indiscriminately?)

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to create a batch file to copy files or folders in a specified directory and append the date and time to their names.
Here's my actual code:

```
@echo off
Set _bpath=T:\Backup\
if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop
Set _file=%~n1%
Set _ext=%~x1%
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=1234567890 " %%a in ("%time%") Do Set "delims=%%a%%b%%c"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=%delims%" %%G in ("%time%") Do (
   Set _hh=%%G
   Set _min=%%H
   Set _ss=%%I
   Set _ms=%%J
)
copy %1 "%_bpath%%_file%(%date:/=-% %_hh%h%_min%m%_ss%s)%_ext%"
shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

This one works for files only and I could adapt it easily for folders with `xcopy /E %1 "%_bpath%%_file%(%date:/=-% %_hh%h%_min%m%_ss%s)` but I would like to avoid dealing with two batch files.

So how to copy/rename them indiscriminately (I have try with copy, xcopy and robocopy without success) or how to distinguish them to create two IF branch? (Using %~x1% is too unreliable...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful to you, see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script) question